# Check for bool is checking for an object instead

Tags: javascript

I've created this utility method in JS:

```
function IsAuthenticated(userID)
{
    var isAuthed = false;

    if (userID.length == 0)
        return false;

    // more logic
    if(SomeLogic)
       isAuthed = true;

    return isAuthed;
}
```

When I run something like this, I'm getting an object back rather than type bool:

```
if(IsAuthenticated)
    //code here
```

I assume I need to cast it to a bool?

Comment: sorry posting error I do have return.

Comment: You need to start posting your real code instead of wasting people's time. Removing my answer and not coming back to this question. Good luck.

Comment: I don't like developers with their nose in the air.  Lets put it that way.

Comment: No, not removing it.  There is 100% truth in my profile.  There are a ton of egoistical developers who think they know it all...and I don't like people like this.  Point of the story is, we're all a team...everyone in this forum is part of a global team, that is to help one another with pain points when they hit a wall in code, need advice, or whatever it is.  Nobody is better than anyone else.  It makes complete sense.  Our profession has turned into a lot of know-it-alls rather than people who work as a team.  That does not go for everyone but the  majority out there.

Comment: Anyone who doesn't understand my profile is probably the type of developer I'm painting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IsAuthenticated` refers to the function with the name “IsAuthenticated” and is not a function call. If you use the `typeof` operator on `IsAuthenticated` you will get `"function"`:

```
alert(typeof IsAuthenticated);
```

So try this instead:

```
var userID = /* … */;
if (IsAuthenticated(userID)) {
    //code here
}
```

Comment: ok so you're never able to first set a returned value from a method to a var first?  I don't want to put in the full function into an if statement, it's hacky.  (nothing against you)

Comment: It doesn't matter either way.  I should be able to set that function call to a var.  Either way I get false every time no matter what.  I know it's entering the SomeLogic for the setting of true but it's returning false ultimately for some reason still even though it's hitting the line to set it to true in the IsAuthenticated method

Answer (score 1):

Try `return isAuthed` instead of just `isAuthed`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
return isAuthed;
```